# I want to animate 5-6 separate elements on a single page with jQuery. I'm concerned about older browsers

Tags: jquery, animation, web

I want to animate 5-6 separate images to move across the page once a specific element is clicked. I want to keep this animation under 1-2 seconds.

I'm concerned about how fast this will run on not-so-great computers.

I imagine the code will look something like this with a different class for each image:

```
$("#startAnimation").click(function(){
$(".toBeAnimated").animate({ 
    marginLeft: "+=250px",
}, 1000 );
});
```

Do you guys have any recommendations? Will this be too much?

Thanks!

Comment: depends on how big the images are and what else is going on at the same time

Answer (score 2):

The way jQuery animation works, the animation will always complete in the amount of time you specify.  Even in a really slow browser on a slow computer, the animation will still complete in the desired time.

The issue is how smooth the animation will appear vs. how jumpy it gets.  In a slower browser/slower computer, there isn't enough CPU to show lots of separate frames and make the animation run smoothly so it moves in bigger steps, but it still finishes in the desired time.

So worst case, the animation jerky or jumpy on slower computers.  If you are trying to avoid showing the animation when it would be jumpy, then that's a little bigger project.  You have to devise some sort of run-time test that tests the capabilities of the host computer to run your animation and, if you discern that the host computer is on the slow side, then you skip the animation on that computer.  The general idea is that you run some test animation that is representative of what you will be doing upon page load and count the number of frames that you seem to have time for.

After some experimentation, you set some threshold that if you see less than X frames per second in your test animation, you set a cookie that you should not use animation on this computer.  You can set the cookie for expiration in a couple months so you will periodically rerun the test in case the host capabilities change.  In future page visits, you first check the cookie and if the cookie is present, you use the test result from the cookie rather than running the test again.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I suppose if it all finishes in the same time, it won't matter much anyway.

Comment: I added more about how you would test to see how fast a computer is.

Comment: For what it’s worth I used this approach on a recent project. 7-8 elements had to animate within 500ms, then a different 7-8 the next 500ms. I ended up using CSS transitions for newer browsers which are very fast (hardware accelerated) and falling back to animating `top` for IE. IE9 coped admirably with this, but IE7 and 8 were jerky to the point that it impacted on the general feel of the site. In the end I ripped out the animation for IE7 and 8 and had a static change of state. One year later: one complaint, and that was only because the user was testing side by side with Chrome.